# how to read firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

This is my data structure: many clubs, each club has address. I tried to make the database flat.

Now I want to load a few club info on table view. When I swipe down iPhone screen, it will load next a few club info.

[image]

This is my code. But it loads all club info. How can I load only a few club, and load next a few club when user swipe down?

```
func loadClubs() {

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("club").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            //print("clubs: \(snapshot)")
            let array:NSArray = snapshot.children.allObjects as NSArray
            for obj in array {
                let snapshot:DataSnapshot = obj as! DataSnapshot
                if let childSnapshot = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    if let clubName = childSnapshot["name"] as? String {
                        print(clubName)
                    }
                }
            }
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Firebase's queries support pagination, but it's slightly different from what you're used to. Instead of working with offsets, Firebase uses so-called anchor values to determine where to start.

Getting the items for the first page is easy, you just specify a limit to the number of items to retrieve:

```
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    query = ref.child("club").queryOrderedByKey().limitToFirst(10)

    query.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

Now within the block, keep track of the key of the last item you've shown to the user:

```
   for obj in array {
        let snapshot:DataSnapshot = obj as! DataSnapshot
        if let childSnapshot = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            lastKey = childSnapshot.key
            if let clubName = childSnapshot["name"] as? String {
                print(clubName)
            }
        }
    }
```

Then to get the next page, construct a query that starts at the last key you've seen:

```
    query = ref.child("club").queryOrderedByKey().startAt(lastKey).limitToFirst(11)
```

You'll need to retrieve one more item than your page size, since the anchor item is retrieve in both pages.

Answer (score 0):

i think the right way make reference to array of elements,
and make variable for index

```
var i = 0;
var club = null;
club = loadClubs(index); // here should return club with specified index;
                         // and increment index in loadClubs func,
                         // also if you need steped back --- and one more 
                         // argument to function, for example
                         // loadClubs(index, forward) // where forward is 
                         // boolean that says in which way we should 
                         // increment or decrement our index
```

so in your example will be something like this:

```
func loadClubs(index, forward) {

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("club").observe(data => {
        var club = data[index];
        if(forward){
        index ++
        }else{
        index--
        }
    return club;
    })    
}
```